# Firefox cannot log in to web sites

Tags: firefox

I cannot login to certain websites on Firefox 30. Previously, I was shown a prompt asking for a username and password. Now, I get no prompt and a blank page.

This prevents me from using Firefox to access my university accounts. The problem persists after resetting Firefox.

The problem does not occur on websites that have their own login pages, such as Google.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First off, try to make sure it isn't a problem with said websites. If you can, try opening the problem websites in another browser, such as Google Chrome. If they still don't work on those browsers, it is most likely an issue with the websites themselves.

If not, Mozilla has a page pertaining to this issue, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-login-issues-on-websites-require-passwords. You could try the solutions there.

If those don't work, you could try disabling the pop-up blocker. Click on the Menu Button, go to options, and go to the "Content" tab. Uncheck the "Block Pop-up windows" box and click "OK."

You could try just installing a fresh copy of Firefox at https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/.